# Extract form-data PHP

Tags: php, api, post, postman

Can someone tell me how to get the data from post request body(form-data)?
This is how I am calling the API using Postman:
[image]

I am printing the input using below code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $data;
```

This is the output that I get:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycHQ9xxbmOdQAcZNF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testFile"; filename="abc.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

Name,Value
test,QA
contact,789789
------WebKitFormBoundarycHQ9xxbmOdQAcZNF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testData"

['aa','bbbb']
------WebKitFormBoundarycHQ9xxbmOdQAcZNF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testBool"

true
------WebKitFormBoundarycHQ9xxbmOdQAcZNF--
```

How can extract the csv data, testData array, and testBool value from the form-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do this manually. Ignore `php://input` read the data from the [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobals. The data comes preparsed there.

Comment: I tried printing those 2 values and I got empty array. 
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
The above 2 lines gives me following response:
array(
)
array(
)

Comment: Well, you need to post the Data to get them in the $_POST-Array.

Comment: @Bernhard I am using post to send the data as you can see in the above screenshot of postman

Comment: this will not work on put method

Comment: @May'Habit — The question is about a multipart form data POST request where it will work.